# Black Rectangle on booting 14.04 LTS covering Grub Options

Tags: boot

Every time start my laptop the black rectangle appears and covers and hides all the boot options (like Ubuntu, Memtest, or any other OS installed on different partition of same Hard disk).

Sometimes boot options appears without black rectangle after pressing any key or if I forced shutdown by pressing and holding power button and start the system.

I also installed only Ubuntu on friends laptop which is also having same problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That happens when ubuntu is the only installed OS.
You have to edit the following file:

```
sudo nano /etc/default/grub
```

Then you have to replace the following line:

```
GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT= ...
```

with this one:

```
GRUB_TIMEOUT=5
```

(Or any timing of your like != 0)

And finally, regenerate the Grub configuration to make it active:

```
sudo update-grub
```